# How to optimally change item.OrderNum fields to match list order

Tags: algorithm, list, math, sorting

I have list of objects with OrderNum fields.

The OrderNum fields have to match the list order (but *are not required to be continuous*).

Easy solution. Reset every OrderNum when list order changes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].OrderNum = i;
}
```

But as the OrderNum are stored in SQL, **the smaller amount of OrderNum are reset, the better**. When OrderNum have to be reset, the changes can be big. There are 32 bits to use. The ordered list is retrieved by:

```
SELECT * FROM orderable_items ORDER BY order_num;
```

The actual programming language is C#.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of initially having even distribution so there would always be enough number space between the items to insert other items. I just never really have the **initial** list. Just some version that can have almost anything in OrderNum. Most of the lists are sorted though. Maybe finding longest increasing subsequence would help?

Comment: Do you know what kind of changes you can expect, or do you want a general reordering function that changes as few numbers as possible?

Comment: Mostly one new item appearing / changing place in list. Though sometimes there are no sane OrderNums to start with. I was looking for a general solution, but it'd be also possible to e.g. move one item successfully or fall back to renumbering them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the numbers are sparsely spaced, you can do the following:

- Compute the target index in every element in the original list
- Compute the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) (O(nlogn)) on the indices

  - Leave the OrderNum unchanged on the elements in the computed subsequence
  - Change the OrderNums on the rest of the elements so that they fall into the appropriate gaps

This assumes there's enough space between the original OrderNums. After several such reorderings you might need to readjust the numbers so that it is the case.